# Recaptcha V2 returns bool(false) hosted on one domain but not others?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've implemented Recaptcha v2 with one hosting company (1&1) without issue. I've used the same code framework with another hosting company (XILO) and Recaptcha always returns bool(false). I've run the same code locally (MAMP) and it works perfectly in that environment too.

I've double checked the keys are correct and, of course, that the domain names (including localhost) are listed correctly with Google.

Inspecting the variable $recaptchaResult, it is always bool(false) and, consequently, $recaptchaResultObject is Null.

Its clearly an environmental issue and I will also raise this with XILO hosting.

I would be interested if anyone else has encountered this issue (i.e. working in one environment, but not another).

My PHP code...

```
// Recaptcha handling
$recaptchaResponse = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

if(empty($recaptchaResponse)) {

    echo "You must complete the Recaptcha challenge in order to submit your enquiry";
    http_response_code(400);
    exit;

} else {

    # Now post to Recaptcha
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array('secret' => $recaptchaSecret, 'response' => $recaptchaResponse, 'remoteip' => $remoteIp);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $recaptchaResult = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $recaptchaResultObject = json_decode($recaptchaResult);

    // Check hostname is client's domain
    # $thisServer = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //removed since UseCanonicalName and ServerName settings cannot be guaranteed immutable on shared server

    $thisServer = 'clientdomain.com';

    var_dump($recaptchaResult);


    if(
        ($recaptchaResultObject->hostname == $thisServer ||
         $recaptchaResultObject->hostname == 'www.' + $thisServer)
         && 
         $recaptchaResultObject->success == TRUE
        ) {

    } else {

        // Fatal error
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again. (Recaptcha)";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($recaptchaResult)` right after it's assignment. What's the output?

Comment: $recaptchaResult yields bool(false)

Comment: Then do `echo error_get_last()` instead of `var_dump($recaptchaResult)`

Comment: An array is return with three iterations of: Array ( 
    [type] => 2 [message] => file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found 
    [file] => /home/abeleca1/public_html/mailerv3R.php [line] => 58 )

Comment: Line 58 being   $recaptchaResult = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

Comment: Do you have access to the `php.ini` file? You should set `allow_url_fopen` to true

Comment: Xilo have confirmed that allow_url_fopen is false (and they won't allow it to be changed). So I think that I will have to look at using cURL. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, glad to help

Comment: For anyone with similar issues on shared servers, switching to cURL works. $data = array('secret' => $recaptchaSecret, 'response' => $recaptchaResponse,'remoteip' => $remoteIp);
$options = curl_init();
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$recaptchaResult = curl_exec($options);
@HtmHell - thanks for  the pointers!